# Waiting for Headers error while apt-get update

Tags: apt, 16.10

I am always stuck at the following error. I use ubuntu version 16.10

```
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
Ign:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main all Packages
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main Translation-en_IN
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu yakkety/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
0% [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]
```

Please help. I have already check for other answer with no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Ubuntu 16.10 is not the latest LTS version and you should upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04.

Comment: 17.04 is NOT an LTS release.  This may be a silly question but are you connected to the Internet?  e.g. ping ppa.launchpad.net or see if http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/web/ubuntu comes up in your browser.  I'm assuming, perhaps incorrectly, that the repos you are trying to load and current and active.

Comment: Please check your internet connection! DO as jones said...

Comment: @jones0610, this may be a silly question but for those who may not be using Ubuntu regularly.

Answer (score 4):

Just got out of this issue after spending 5 hours trying to figure out what was wrong.
It is either your mirror through which Ubuntu is accessing packages or your service provider is blocking something. 
I would recommend:

1. Check if the current server that you're using is accessible through the browser. If it's not, use another mirror. Go to 'Software & Updates' and choose a mirror from among the ones available at 'Download from'.
2. Check the sources.list file in /etc/apt/ and comment out all the lines that access packages from the mirror that wasn't reachable.

If changing mirror doesn't work, check if you are able to get things updated using `sudo apt-get update` after you connect to a different ISP. Probably try with your phone's hotspot? Might just work. (Worked for me.)

Comment: Using another network solved the problem for me :) Still need to figure out which source caused the problem though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try one more time to leave some comments about this issue on this forum. It is to help others, so think twice before deleting it.

I started seeing this problem on a VM running xenial , on which  I had not changed any config for some time before the issue manifested.

I checked my sources.list and verified I could access the repo URLs using wget.
e.g. `wget archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`

This worked fine. So I could rule out firewall or network issues connecting to the repo hosts.

I started  `tcpdump -i [ifname]  host archive.ubuntu.com` and could see traffic during wget,  but nothing when I ran `apt-get update`.

I googled and found nothing helpful, so I'd like to leave this for people who might 
be in a similiar situation.

The point is you may have a proxy setup and not know it, as in my case.
The ISP/datacentre hosting my VM had added it in my /etc/apt/apt.conf , and this proxy had evidently stopped working correctly.

If you're in a similiar situation you can see if , wittingly or unwittingly , you have a proxy set with

```
grep -r Proxy /etc/apt
```

In my case I removed the offending Proxy definition, and apt-get worked as expected once more.